# How can I show how much water got saved on this order (making use of the number of items bought) on a thank-you-page?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, array, count

More detailed: I'd like to use the the number of items which were bought by somebody and multiplicate it with a number, to show how much water somebody saved.

```
    function random_message(){
    
    $count = 0;
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $items ) {
        // Count + 1
        $count++;
    }
$mes = array('Message 12', 'Message 13', 'Message 14');
$multiplier = 7950;
shuffle($mes);
echo 'you saved ' . $count * $multiplier . 'l water';
//echo 'With this order ' . $mes[0];
}
add_shortcode( 'random_message', 'random_message' );
```

I wrote this code to my functions.php inside of my child-theme.
At the moment I get an error: [Screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AikSNhBAk4tevj896Q-kH-e1REZ5)

Comment: "an error" is too vague. Please include the complete error message, so we can help you.

Comment: You're getting a PHP error: `Call to a member function get_items() on null`. That sounds like you're using something along the lines of `$some_class->get_items()` somewhere, but `$some_class` isn't initialized. [Here's an answer on a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28593099/1094518)

Comment: Also: rather than posting a screenshot of the error, please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/374432/edit) and paste it in as text (feel free to remove any sensitive info like directory paths, etc). This will make it easier for people having a similar problem to search for answers, and also make it easier for us to try to answer your question.